# TextView size issue android

Tags: android, textview, size, android-alertdialog

I set texview size from dimens.xml . but it's behave different in different mobile screen like , In honor 6x device looks big font and intex mobile look like small but i apply same textsize.

Here my code :-

```
private fun changeStandardDialog(standardList: ArrayList<Category>) {
    val factory = LayoutInflater.from(this)
    val standardDialog = factory.inflate(R.layout.select_standard_diolog, null)
    selectedStandardId = SettingsHandler(this).getSettings("default_standard")

    for (item in standardList) {
        val rdbtn = RadioButton(this)
        rdbtn.id = item.id
        rdbtn.text = item.title

        if (selectedStandardId.toInt() == item.id) {
            rdbtn.isChecked = true
        }
        rdbtn.textSize = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.radio_text_size)
        val textColor = Color.parseColor("#323642")
        rdbtn.setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(textColor));

        rdbtn.setPadding(20, 30, 30, 30)
        standardDialog.selectSubjectList.addView(rdbtn)
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyDialogTheme)
            .setTitle(R.string.selectStd)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok") { dialog, whichButton ->
                if (standardDialog.selectSubjectList.checkedRadioButtonId > 0) {
                    changeSelectedStandardTitle(standardDialog.selectSubjectList.checkedRadioButtonId)
                    settingHandler.updateSettingsViaKey("default_standard", standardDialog.selectSubjectList.checkedRadioButtonId.toString())
                }
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, whichButton ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            .setView(standardDialog)
            .create()
            .show()
}
```

My dimens.xml for R.dimen.radio_text_size :-

```
<dimen name="radio_text_size">6sp</dimen>
```

Here i use 6 sp for Radio button Textview show differnt screen textsize Left side Honor 6x ScreenShot and Right side Intex

[image]

Comment: use `sp` insted of `dp`

Comment: i use sp bro ple check out my code @ShubhamVala

Comment: I believe that's due to different resolutions of both devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of `TextView#setTextSize(float)` you'll see that it treats the value you give it as a `sp` value. When you're using `getDimension` that's converting the `sp` value from `dimens.xml` into a pixel value, when you then set that value onto the TextView it's converting that pixel value as if it was a sp value into another (different) pixel value.

You'll either just want to use your sp value in code like

```
rbbtn.textSize = 6f
```

or you'll want to specify that you're using pixels and use the value you've retrieved from dimens

```
rdbtn.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, resources.getDimension(R.dimen.radio_text_size))
```

Comment: rbbtn.textSize = 6f this is run perfectly @hibob

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
rdbtn.textSize = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,resources.getDimension(R.dimen.radio_text_size), resources.getDisplayMetrics());
```